# Log out NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a Log out link in NetSuite I know that the code below works but when i place it in netsuite it just gets outputted as text. I'm just having trouble understanding where in NetSuite it actually goes. It does not work when I place it in a template.

```
 <@ var isLoggedIn = "<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','email')%>" != ""; if(isLoggedIn) { <li class="dropdown-menu1"><a href="<NLLOGOUTURL>"> Log out </a></li>  } @>
```

Answer (score 1):

isLoggedIn has been replaced with isLoggedIn2 FYI, or at least for the company that I work for this was the case and recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You might:

A) Replicate the scripts called when you log out

B) Clear cookies and redirect to X page.

Comment: I know how to do the log out -- I just don't know how/where to place it in netsuite for it to actually read as code. Since getCurrentAttribute is a server side call how to i make a template read that as a server side call placing <script> tags did not work.

Answer (score 0):

'isLoggedIn' method is no longer supported or recommended. This method works correctly in the Checkout domain but may return false when used in the Shopping domain even when the user is logged in. The method is currently being use in pre_Denali versions of SuiteCommerce Advanced. If you encounter session issues in those bundles, contact support to migrate to using the isLoggedIn2() method.

-- posted today on NetSuite's forum by an employee